# How can I make ember dynamically bind to different elements?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, models

I'm trying to dynamically generate a set of input boxes for my ember application. Basically, depending on some JSON will determine what data I'm needing to save (It might have fields such as `title`, `author` and `publisher`).

This means I'm wanting to bind them to my ember model through the normal templating if possible. Basically they will go into a `{  "key" : value }` object in my Model.

The only thing is figuring out if it's possible to bind a value, which the variable name can be found from a variable name. In PHP for example you would do `$$varname`

Sorry if this isn't clear or isn't possible.

Comment: This is possible, I've seen this already in a meetup. can't remember the exact code. I'll try to find something and come back to update.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Thanks, I'll be waiting :)

Comment: sorry my friend. "No can do" at this time :(